# Menu Item Click Event gets fired even when Tool Strip is Disabled

Tags: c#, .net, windows, menubar

I have a Tool Strip which I enable/disable based on the logged-in user role. This works well. However, there is a Menu Item inside that tool strip which has a Short Cut Key. The Click Event gets fired through Short Cut Key even when the containing Tool Strip is disabled.

Should I disable all Menu Items recursively inside the Tool Strip if I need disable Tool Strip? Is not that sufficient that I disabled the Tool Strip?